# execvp failed: no such file or directory

Tags: pipe, fork, fopen, execvp, dup

I'm writing a program in C that reads from a file (e.g a file called ffff in the same folder of my .c source file): this files contains two command:

```
ls -l
tac
```

My program open this file, reads the commands and the relative arguments and by using a pipe shows me the same output of

```
ls -l | tac
```

I have used the get line and I have thought to use `execvp` but the output is

> execvp error: No such file or directory.

Can you help me? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int mypipe[2];
 FILE *stream;
 char *line=NULL;
 size_t len=0;
 ssize_t read;

 /*controllo il numero degli argomenti passati*/
 if(argc != 2){
 fprintf(stderr, "no such arguments \n");
 exit(1);
 }

/*apro il file in sola lettura*/
stream=fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(stream==NULL){
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*apro la pipe*/
if(pipe(mypipe) == -1){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error pipe\n");
   exit (1);
}

if(fork()==0){
   close(1); /*chiudo lo stdout*/
   dup(mypipe[1]); /*rimpiazzo lo stdout con la pipe*/
   close(mypipe[0]); /*chiudo la read della pipe*/
   close(mypipe[1]);

   read=getline(&line, &len, stream);

   execvp(argv[1], &line);
   perror("execvp failed");
   exit (1);
}
if(fork()==0){
   close(0); /*chiudo lo stdin*/
   dup(mypipe[0]); /*rimpiazzo lo stdin con la pipe read*/
   close(mypipe[1]); /*chiudo la write della pipe*/
   close(mypipe[0]);

   read=getline(&line, &len, stream);
   execvp(argv[1], &line);
   perror("execvp 2 failed");
   exit (1);
}
close(mypipe[0]);
close(mypipe[1]);
wait(0);
wait(0);
free(line);
fclose(stream);
exit (0);
}
```

Comment: 1) execvp() needs a full pathname for its first argument. 2) execvp needs (a pointer to) a **NULL terminated** array of pointer arguments for its second argument.

Comment: 1) Ok i have change the pathname. 2) How can i do this?

Comment: `char *lines[2] =  {line, NULL};` , and use that in `execvp(fullpath , lines);`

Comment: Ok i have repaired the arguments of execvp but the output now is >Permission Denied